# is it correct to say 'Just called' when you telling someone

Tags: idioms

I really don't understand. Because ***just*** is present but ***called*** I think is the past tense.

Comment: *Just* is an adverb, it's neither present nor past tense.

Comment: "Just" = "just now" = "right now", so anything after "just" is *now* in the past, if you blink you'll miss it...

Answer (score 2):

As an adverb, [**just**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/just) can mean very recently, or in the immediate past, and as an adverb, it doesn't have a tense, it merely describes how far back in the past the event took place (i.e. not long ago at all). *I just + [past simple]* is a common construction in English, for example:

> - I just saw him.
> - I just arrived.
> - I just got home.
> - I just called him.

Comment: Equally, *just* can be used to refer to an action in the future. *I will call them in just a few minutes.*

Answer (score 1):

The word "just" as an adverb has different manings, one of which is a short time ago or rcently.  You cannot say it's used only in the present. However, you can say that it's usually used with the present perfect in BrE to express recently happened events.  As for AmE, the use of the just with the past simple is also common. So the following sentences are grammatical:

He just called you.

He has just called you,

You called when he had left.